# force:recordData returning null results

Tags: lightning-aura-components, force-recorddata

I'm working on a lightning component and I'm trying to retrieve lead record details through
**force:recorddata** but actually it's returning null results.

My component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="leadRecord" type="Object"/>        
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.dohitme}"/>
   <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="status"
    targetFields="{!v.leadRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
    />
</aura:component>
```

My Controller:

```
({
    dohitme : function(component, event, helper) {
        var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));
        var speedtolead = component.get("v.leadRecord").Status;
        console.log(speedtolead);
    }
})
```

Did I miss something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/documentation), you can see they note the following:

> force:recordData loads data asynchronously since it may retrieve data from the server. To track when the record is loaded or changed, **use the recordUpdated event** or place a change handler on targetRecords or targetFields.

Since it's async, you won't have any value in the initialization as you're attempting to do. As it mentioned, you can leverage the [recordUpdated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm) event

> The event fired when the record is loaded, updated, or deleted.

This will ensure it's loaded before you attempt to do anything within the record. If it does fail to load, you can check your `recordLoadError` attribute (which you used in `recordData`, but need to create the attribute)

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="leadRecord" type="Object"/>        
<aura:attribute name="recordLoadError" <type="String"/> <!-- store error -->
   <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="Status"
    targetFields="{!v.leadRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
    recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" <!-- put logic on load -->
    />
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    recordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
        var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;
        if (changeType === "LOADED") {
            var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
            var speedtolead = component.get("v.leadRecord").Status;
        } else if (changeType === "ERROR") {
            ...
        } /* also have REMOVED and CHANGED */
        
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer do you want me to create a separate action named recordUpdated in controller

Comment: if that's all your current action does (`dohitme`), you can just rename it and remove the `aura:handler` for init as you won't need it. You want to handle the `recordUpdated` event.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to lightning actually change type is returning ERROR only. How to debug the scenario

Comment: Try capitalizing the `Status` field (as that's its actual API name) and making sure your custom field is exactly the same as the API name as well: `fields="Status,Speed_to_Dial_main__c"`

Comment: Same issue after we have updated

Comment: In the `changeType === "Error"`, what does `console.log('Error : ' + component.get("v.recordLoadError"));` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127585/discussion-between-kris-goncalves-and-pavan-tej).